# Sort strings as DateTime in DataGridView

Tags: c#, string, sorting, datetime, datagridview

I developed a program that is operated by multiple computers connected to the same network, and as some of those computers use different DateTime formats, I converted the output DateTime to string in order to standardise it using the British format (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss).

However, when the output is displayed in DataGridView, it's not being sorted chronologically (the most recent ones should be on top) due to the fact the output is formatted as string, e.g.: 30/06/2015 13:00:00 is displayed above 03/07/2015 13:00:00 as '3' is the 1st character of the 1st string and it's greater than '0', 1st character of the 2nd string.

My question is how do I set my DataGridView to sort those strings in chronological order?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you sort them as a `DateTime`, not as a `string`? Can you please show your work as well?

Comment: @SonerGönül it is being sorted as `string` because otherwise it will lose the standardisation, here's the code:
`targetTable.Sort(timeStarted, ListSortDirection.Descending);`
`timeStarted` is the column that has the dates I want to sort my `DataGridView` by, and that column is the one with the strings.

Comment: you do not need to convert to control the display format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not convert it to String. You should use date time object only and format it using DefaultCellStyle.Format

Comment: I fully agree with Subba Rao. However, there are simple solutions to operate specific sort on a string column if the dataGridView is not bounded. If bounded, it is still possible by defining an hidden column where the items are sorted according to your specific comparer, and to catch the user actions (click on sort arrows) to sort on hidden column instead of sorting on visible one.